# Deciding intersection between ordered arrays complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

**Problem:** Given two sorted arrays A[] and B[] of size n each, check whether or not they have a non-empty intersection (I don't need the intersection itself, only the decision)

**Solution:** Making a binary sort in B[] for each element of A[] gives a O(n lg n) solution. Iterating each array from start to end (doing something very similar to Merge from Mergesort) gives O(n) solution.

I was wondering if there's a better (in terms of complexity) solution. I'm pretty sure there isn't, but I was looking for "hey, if you give me a better solution, I can sort a vector in o(n lg n), which is impossible"-kind-of-argument

Answer (score 2):

Read the problem again - `"Given two sorted arrays ..."`.

The initial proposed sort is not needed, which leads you to an `O(n)` solution to do the merge-sort-like process.

You can't do much better than a merge-sort-like process, remember you can stop early if an intersection is found.

**If they weren't sorted:**

A hash-map-based solution would technically be `O(n)` - Insert all elements from A into a hash-map (`O(n)`). Do lookups for each of the elements in B (`O(n)`).

For a sorting solution, since you only need a decision, you only need to sort A and loop through B, doing an `O(log n)` lookup in A for each element in B, and stop once you find an item. You won't do better than `O(n log n)`, but you can cut down on as much as half the work if a match is found early.